# Multiple format options in Python

Tags: python

In Python,  how can I do multiple formats at once:

So I want to make a number have no decimal places and have a thousands separator:

num = 80000.00

I want it to be 80,000

I know I can do these two things serepatly, but how would I combine them:

```
"{:,}".format(num) # this will give me the thousands separator
"{0:.0f}".format(num) # this will give me only two decimal places
```

So is it possible to combine these together??

Comment: should be `"{:,.2f}"` if you want the two decimal places

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine the two format strings.  The comma goes first after the colon:

```
>>> "{:,.0f}".format(80000.0)
'80,000'
```

Note that you can also use the free `format()` function instead of the method `str.format()` when formatting only a single value:

```
>>> format(80000.0, ",.0f")
'80,000'
```

**Edit**: The `,` to include a thousands separator was introduced in Python 2.7, so the above conversions don't work in Python 2.6.  In that version you will need to roll your own string formatting.  Some ad-hoc code:

```
def format_with_commas(x):
    s = format(x, ".0f")
    j = len(s) % 3
    if j:
         groups = [s[:j]]
    else:
         groups = []
    groups.extend(s[i:i + 3] for i in range(j, len(s), 3))
    return ",".join(groups)
```

Comment: I forgot to add... I am in Python 2.6... so I know that this gets a bit tricky with format... I have to specify something other wise I get a zero length operator error?

Comment: @ChristopherH: Please update your question with this information.  There is no way to include a thousands spearator in Python 2.6, so the first conversion in your question won't work.

Comment: no problem... it works on another system I have using 2.7... I can figure out a workaround for the 2.6 system so I'll leave the question as is since it answered it for one system